# create pandas pivottable with a long multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe df with the shape (4573,64) that I'm trying to pivot. The last column is an 'id' with two possible string values 'old' and 'new'. I would like to set the first 63 columns as index and then have the 'id' column across the top with values being the count of 'old' or 'new' for each index row.
I've created a list object out of columns labels that I want as index named cols.

I tried the following:

```
df.pivot(index=cols, columns='id')['id']
```

this gives an error: 'all arrays must be same length'
also tried the following to see if I can get sum but no luck either:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=cols,values=['id'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

any ides greatly appreciated

Comment: Are columns names converted to `list` like `cols = df.columns[:4].tolist()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need convert columns names to list and then aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,4,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[1,1,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,1,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[0,0,6,9,2,4],
                   'id':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E id
0  4  1  1  0  a
1  4  1  1  0  a
2  4  9  5  6  a
3  5  4  7  9  b
4  5  2  1  2  b
5  4  3  0  4  b

cols = df.columns.tolist()
df1 = df.groupby(cols)['id'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
id       a  b
B C D E      
4 1 1 0  2  0
  3 0 4  0  1
  9 5 6  1  0
5 2 1 2  0  1
  4 7 9  0  1
```

Solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=cols,columns='id',aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
print (df1)
id       a  b
B C D E      
4 1 1 0  2  0
  3 0 4  0  1
  9 5 6  1  0
5 2 1 2  0  1
  4 7 9  0  1
```

Comment: jezrael thanks. trying your solution but getting an error "Length of passed values is 4573, index implies 0"  is the issue somehow the number of rows I wonder. any other thoughs?

Comment: @whada - So `cols = df.columns.tolist()` not working? What is your pandas version?

Comment: the pandas version Im running is 0.23.0. my cols variable is already a list that I've created using .columns.tolist()  similar to what you have provided above. now it looks like when it is passed into the pivot or pivot_table  it doesnt like it

Comment: @whada - How working omit last column `id` like `df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=cols[:-1] ,columns='id',aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)` ?

Comment: hm, still returns the same error "Length of passed values is 4573, index implies 0"

Comment: btw.do I need to reset existing index before I do the operation you are suggesting above?

Comment: just found a thread talking about pandas bug since ver.23. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21624 is that the case here I wonder. if so and setting a multiindex is not recommended would there be a workaround that would fit my purpose here

Comment: @whada possible solution is first replace nans to some value not existed in data e. g df = df. fillna(-100), apply solution and last df = df. replace(-100, np. nan)

Comment: good stuff, yes that's what I just posted in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a thread online talking about a possible bug in pandas 0.23.0 where the pandas.pivot_table() will not accept the multiindex as long as it contains NaN's (link to github in comments). My workaround was to do

```
df.fillna('empty', inplace=True)
```

then the solution below:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=cols,columns='id',aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

as proposed by jezrael will work as intended hence the answer accepted.